# Showing 06:00 instead of 6am in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

If you choose to view a week or day the left column will by default show 6am, 7am and so on. How do i go about to make it show 06:00, 07:00 and so on instead?

Edit: im talking about the left column i weekview and dayview that by default is 6am, 7am, 8am. NOT the timestamp in the events.

To further point out the problem i want to changes the am/pm to 24hour times for the highlighted part of the image: http://bildr.no/view/770893[image]

Comment: look at the last part of my answer it changes just that

Comment: there i go! +1 and accepted answere to you Breezer, thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

check this out

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/timeFormat/

you should always check documentation before anything else just a tip

try this

```
    day: 'h:mm{ - h:mm}', // 5:00 - 6:30
    week: 'h:mm{ - h:mm}', // 5:00 - 6:30
```

or this one might be it

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/agenda/axisFormat/
i think it's this one tbh :P

like this

```
axisFormat: 'h:mm{ - h:mm}',
```

**FOR A 24 HOUR CLOCK U CHANGE THE CONTENT TO**

```
axisFormat: 'H:mm',
```

Comment: ive read it. i manage to edit the event times, but what i want to edit is the left column where you have "allday" event on top in weekview and dayview

Comment: then you would have seen that there is http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/View_Option_Hash/

Comment: and cmon why in hell do i get minus for -.- sometimes you just hate this site :P perhaps it would have been that i hadn't replied

Comment: It was not what i wanted :P u thought i ment timeformat of the events in the calendar, but i mean the column in week/day that shows time spans (6am, 7am, 8am++)

Comment: yeah i know i understood that look at the last link in my answer

Comment: I think Breezer's answer deserves a vote not a minus. His answer helps and not a nonsense. I will vote up. I know this works and have tested it.